# Django dictionary shopping cart

Tags: django, dictionary

I am trying to delete my dictionary cart in django but it' not work

```
def deleteCart(request, id):
    myCart = request.session.get('shopcart')
    
    if id in myCart.keys():
        myCart.pop(id)
        
    request.session['shopcart'] = myCart
    return render(request, 'home/check.html', {'myCart': myCart})
```

Comment: i try to fix and it work: myCart.pop(str(id), None)

Answer (score 0):

try with `remove()`, i.e.:

```
myCart.remove(id)
```

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove